# JSON.stringify and JSON.parse doesn't work with date objects

Tags: javascript, json

This happens in Google Chrome:

```
var obj  = {"date" : new Date()};
var objJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
//"{"date":"2014-04-30T07:35:29.002Z"}"
var objBack = JSON.parse(objJSON);
```

objBack is not a date object is a string. I need to do:

```
objBack.date = new Date(objBack.date)
```

Is there a way to get back a Date Object directly?

I need that because I've a complex object (with lots of dates there) which is stored in localStorage using JSON.stringify, after I get back this object from localStorage using JSON.parse, so It'd be great get the dates as Date Object not as strings.

Comment: As far as I know there is no other way around, you have to do this objBack.date = new Date(objBack.date)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON.parse or alternative library that will also parse dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120256/json-parse-or-alternative-library-that-will-also-parse-dates)

Comment: @RajeshCP Do you know why is that? I imagine if Google is doing that they've a reason...

Comment: @alasarr: What makes you think Google has anything to do with JSON?

Comment: You're right, Google has anything to do with it, It was my first thought because Google does Google Chrome, but the emacscript spec is not Google's responsibility. Anyway, I imagine that whoever did it has a reason... Why?

Comment: @alasarr: For leaving out dates? I can only speculate. JSON was created by Douglas Crockford. He defined it as a subset of JavaScript literal syntax, with edge cases and options removed to make parsing more straight-forward. JavaScript doesn't have a date literal syntax, so I guess he just didn't want to *add* something. (JSON was purely JS literal syntax with things *removed*.) I would have gone a different way, but then, who knows whether doing so would have prevented JSON being as popular (since early on, most people just used `eval` to parse it).

Comment: Noting that `new Date("2014-04-30T07:35:29.002Z")` produces different results in different browsers.

Comment: @RobG over which browser? I've test in in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD:** the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15120418/1016033 is more general and don't override default `toJSON` method if `Date`.

---

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) calls toJSON method of objects if there is one. So you could add toJSON method to Date prototype.

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) has second argument function that is called for every parsed value and could be used to call `new Date` for some values.

Here is small example of how they works:

```
Date.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    return 'date:' + (+this);
}

var obj = {
    date: new Date,
    s: 'string',
    n: 42
};

console.log(obj);

var json = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(json);

function revive(k, v) {
    if (typeof v == 'string' && v.indexOf('date:') == 0) {
        return new Date(+(v.slice(5)));
    }
    return v;
}

var objBack = JSON.parse(json, revive);

console.log(objBack);
```

The result:

```
~$ node a.js
{ date: Wed Apr 30 2014 12:09:11 GMT+0400 (MSK),
  s: 'string',
  n: 42 }
{"date":"date:1398845351567","s":"string","n":42}
{ date: Wed Apr 30 2014 12:09:11 GMT+0400 (MSK),
  s: 'string',
  n: 42 }
```

Comment: Don't overwrite `Date.prototype.toJSON` if it's present; and if you *do* shim it, shim it with something [that does what the spec says to do](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.44).

Comment: It works, but @T.J.Crowder is right, we should implement toJSON according the spec

Comment: @T.J.Crowder @alasar, you're right. After all I would prefer to using second parameter of `stringify` because it's easier for me.